# Line wrapping with left and right aligned text

Tags: html, css

I've got some text which is both left and right aligned on the same line, the problem is that sometimes the text doesn't *fit* on one line so must wrap over to 2 lines. This is fine but the way in which it wraps is not ideal. In the event it doesn't al fit on a single line, i'd like for the *left* text to wrap and the *right* text to remain as it is.

Here's some example HTML:

```
<p class="statute_name">Alkali etc Works Regulation Act 1906 <span class="float_right">4.22</span></p>

<p class="statute_name">Ancient Monuments and Arch­aeological Areas Act 1979 <span class="float_right">2.33, 5.78, 12.86</span></p>

<p class="statute_name">Historic Environment (Amendment) (Scotland) Act 2011 <span class="float_right">12.6, 12.35, 12.86 </span></p>
```

And CSS:

```
.statute_name {
    margin-left: 2em;
    text-indent: -2em;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
}

.float_right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

And a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z35au/

If you adjust the width of the result window, you can see that the 2 sides will overlap, then the right side will move below the left, before finally the left side must wrap and this is how I'd like it to look, but skipping the behaviour which happens before (the overlapping and right side moving below).

I've been through some different left and right align techniques, such as having both sides as different `p` elements and floating them either way, applying a `width` to the *right* part in hopes that it will force the left side to wrap when it hits but it doesn't work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just messed around with the code and the best way I found to do this was to wrap the css in a div, then give this a min-width of 500px. This keeps a generous gap between both pieces of text and allows prevents the text from overlapping.

HTML

```
<div class="text">
    <p class="statute_name">Alkali etc Works Regulation Act 1906 <span class="float_right">4.22</span></p>

    <p class="statute_name">Ancient Monuments and Arch­aeological Areas Act 1979 <span class="float_right">2.33, 5.78, 12.86</span></p>

    <p class="statute_name">Historic Environment (Amendment) (Scotland) Act 2011 <span class="float_right">12.6, 12.35, 12.86 </span></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.statute_name {
    margin-left: 2em;
    text-indent: -2em;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
}

.float_right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.text{
    min-width:500px;
}
```